# How to capture value of an attribute in JavaScript not jQuery

Tags: javascript, getattribute, bootstrap-slider

I want to capture the value of an attribute on an  tag using JavaScript. I am not yet successful doing so.

Here's my HTML markup:

```
<html>
<head>
...
  <!-- bootstrap-slider Plugin -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
...
</head>
<body>
...
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="language_spanish">Spanish</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="language_spanish" type="text" data-provide="slider"
          data-slider-ticks="[0,1,2]"
          data-slider-min="0"
          data-slider-max="2"
          data-slider-step="1"
          data-slider-value="0"
          data-slider-tooltip="show"
          data-identifier="this is what I want to capture"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var spanish = new Slider( '#language_spanish', { formatter } );
spanish.on( 'slideStop', function( value ) {
  alert( value ); // this works perfectly!
  alert( this.getAttribute( 'data-identifier' ) ); // does not work
  alert( spanish.getAttribute( 'data-identifier' ) ); // does not work either
  alert( spanish.attr( 'data-identifier' ) ); // does not work as well
});
```

Is it possible?

**FYI jQuery does not work with bootstrap-slider. Tried and tried and tried and I keep hitting brick walls. JavaScript has been the only way I can use this plugin to retrieve values and attributes.**

Amended to include source of plugin:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/bootstrap-slider.min.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css

Comment: Its always better to add the source of plugin which you are using.

Comment: added it to my OQ @Satpal -- thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) so we can see the problem.

Comment: ? not sure what you mean @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Read the linked help page, and put a **runnable** (live) example demonstrating the problem in the question using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). They're a bit like an on-site version of jsFiddle or codepen. You can load the external resources from http://cdnjs.com.

Comment: well let's see if anyone has successfully use  bootstrap -slider...thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `spanish.element` object which returns the reference of underlying DOM element, then `getAttribute()` method can be used.

```js
var spanish = new Slider('#language_spanish');
console.log(spanish.element.getAttribute( 'data-identifier'))
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>


<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="language_spanish">Spanish</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="language_spanish" type="text" data-provide="slider" data-slider-ticks="[0,1,2]" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="2" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0" data-slider-tooltip="show" data-identifier="this is what I want to capture" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW -- that's the answer @Satpal -- `.element.` -- Thank you so very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the attribute on `spanish`, which is a Slider object, not a DOM object. The slider object does not have a getAttribute method. I suggest you look at the Slider plugin documentation to see if there's a method for retrieving the DOM object's parameters or alternatively keep track of the DOM element separately.

If you use the getAttribute method on a DOM object, it will work just fine like so:

`this.getAttribute( 'data-identifier' )`